# How do I move components within my button horizontally and vertically based on screen width?

Tags: javascript, css

I would like my button, which contains 3 components (1 being on the far left, 2 being in the center, and 3 being on the far right (because of `align-center: space between`), which I need for another variant), to function like this, when the screen size is greater than 560px:

[image: wireframe showing two divs on the left of a container and one div on the right]

where `flex-direction: row` keeps it functioning how I want. Then, I want to change it slightly when the screen width drops below 560px. I would like to move the `1` component above the `2` and `3` components and be centered between them (horizontally), as can be seen here...

[image: wireframe showing final solution with small screen size]

I was able to achieve the solution with the picture when I placed a `div` surrounding component `1` and `2`, but then I cannot achieve the final solution when the screen width is below 560px. I have been able to achieve that solution as well when I pair component `2` and `3` within the same `div` as well, but that makes the wider function not work how I want either.

I imagine there's a way to achieve what I want without enforcing these `div` groupings, but I'm not really sure. I'm also somewhat new to Javascript, so any advice about something I've said would be appreciated too.

Comment: A picture showing what you want to see in breakpoints below 560px would be useful.

Comment: @rushkeldon I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but I added an image with what I'm attempting to achieve in my final solution. Is that the picture you were looking for? I'm not very familiar with breakpoints

Comment: Just what I was looking for.  Are you using a CSS precompiled language like SASS or LESS? Or are you using straight CSS?

Comment: @rushkeldon I should have clarified that the files are written in SCSS, which I sometimes forget when I'm talking to other people about it.

Answer (score 0):

I used a breakpoint to change the ruleset for both the container element (button in your case) and the children.

The below example is in LESS, but you can see the compiled CSS in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/keldon/pen/ExoJowg) by using the dropdown on the CSS panel.

```
@mediumQuery: ~"screen and (max-width:560px)";

.container {
  display : flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  column-gap : 20px;
  border : 2px solid @yellow;
  padding : 10px;
  width : 100vw;
  div {
    display : inline-block;
    border : 2px solid @purple;
    width : 200px;
    height : 100px;
    font-size : 40px;
    line-height : 100px;
    text-align : center;
    &:last-child{
      margin-left: auto;
    }
  }
  @media @mediumQuery {
    display : block;
    flex-direction : unset;
    column-gap : unset;
    border : 2px solid @lightBlue;
    text-align : center;
    div {
      margin : 20px;
      &:first-child {
        display : block;
        margin : auto;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What if the first and third box are set in terms of width and height (not the same though), but the second box changes as the screen size increases/decreases? The images above represent what I'm trying to do, but not perfectly. I want my page to component to function like that, but my boxes are a little more complex than that

Comment: This would still work if your boxes were different widths and heights.

Answer (score 0):

you can put the div you want to be on top into another container and then play with @media queries and adjust how you want

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 560px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
div:nth-child(3) {
  margin-left: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 560px) {
  main {
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  section {
    width: 100%;
  }
  section div {
    margin: auto;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 240px) {
  main {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  div:nth-child(3) {
    margin: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <div>1</div>
  </section>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</main>
```

Comment: What if the first and third box are set in terms of width and height (not the same though), but the second box changes as the screen size increases/decreases? The images above represent what I'm trying to do, but not perfectly. I want my page to component to function like that, but my boxes are a little more complex than that

Comment: if you open console.log in the right side of the screen and shrink the window size you will get the boxes as in the second image